# can we do something about libelous comments?

Tags: discussion

is there anything we can do about libelous remarks?  I have recently been viciously attacked in starkly libelous terms. ok this is the web, you takes your chances, but I think a line must be drawn if this is to remain a (relatively) civilized forum. otherwise it's just another slag-heap.

Comment: and I might add that the attacker has a track record of such libelous comments.  and I do mean "libel" in the legal sense, written defamation.

Comment: Flag as offensive? Use the "contact us" button at the bottom of the page?

Comment: thanks,@sumelic,  I had forgotten about that. but I don't see a way to do that for comments and discussions. :(

Comment: If you hover over a comment, the flag icon should appear to the left. I don't know if this is available for people using the mobile site though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Be nice](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) (not you, the other guy).

<sup>Well, you *too* of course, but you get what I mean.</sup>

If someone does not behave according to this policy, please flag it directly for moderator attention. No matter that this is the web, the same rules as in normal social conduct apply here.

You can flag comments when you hover them:

> [image]

All comment flags appear to ♦ moderators immediately. On posts, only the "in need of moderator intervention", "spam" and "rude or abusive" flags go directly to the moderators. Other flags are first reviewed by the community.

Comment: ok thanks! I don't understand your "you too" comment, but i did not know about the hover thing - I mostly use my mobilr.

Comment: @mobileink in the (android) app, you can tap the comment and then there should be an option as well. On the mobile web page, it is not possible. With 'you too' I meant that you should of course follow the be nice policy, but that it isn't under particular consideration at the moment (instead, the guy you have/had an argument with is under consideration).

Comment: thanks. fwiw I do not think in general think niceness should be enforceable. I'm a big boy, you (i mean not you pwrsobally but anybody) dont have to be nice to me, you can say "that's a stupid idea" and I won't be bothered, but "that's a stupid idea, and you are a lying piece of scum" is different.